# Docker container on windows server

Tags: windows, docker, windows-server-2012, microservices

Are docker containers supported in windows server 2012?
I saw that the windows server 2016 will support them,
but I couldn't find any reference to older versions.

Answer (score 1):

Windows server 2012 lacks the container support that comes with Windows server 2016. As 2012 does not explicitly support docker containers, you can draw your own conclusions :-)